# How to use "\S" in jflex(flex) lexer?

Tags: regex, whitespace, lexer, jflex

I want to match non-space characters, so I defined flex file with JFlex:

```
%%

Value = [\S]+

%%

{Value}   { return MyTokens.Value; }
.         { return MyTokens.BadCharacter; }
```

Then I try the generated java code to analyse the string "abc", but I get:

```
BadCharacter(a)
BadCharacter(b)
BadCharacter(c)
```

If I change the declaration to :

```
Value = [a-z]+
```

Then I can get expected result:

```
Value(abc)
```

Why `\S` is not working? Isn't it mean "non-whitespace"?

Comment: Seems like `\S` is indeed supported by jflex: http://jflex.de/manual.html... FYI, though that's probably not the source of your issue, the brackets are redundant. `\S` can (should be able to) be used alone.

Comment: I found the reason: the version of JFlex I used is `1.4`, which doesn't support `\s`, `\S`. See the changelog of <http://jflex.de/history.html>. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 1):

`\S` should indeed match a non-whitespace codepoint.

From the manual:

> hese meta characters are equivalent to the following:
>   \S  \P{Whitespace}

Edit: I didn't see you already replied in a comment:
`\S` was introduced in [version 1.5](http://jflex.de/changelog.html#jflex-1.5.0).